# Best way to transfer photos from Android 4.4.4 to Windows 7

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung, mtp, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I just upgraded to a Samsung Galaxy s5 running android 4.4.4. On my old phone running gingerbread, I was able to use the USB Mass Storage Device (MSD) feature to browse, delete, and copy photos (to a Windows 7 PC) very quickly since that phone basically acted as a standard USB drive.

On the Galaxy s5, it uses MTP, and trying to perform these same functions is painfully slow. I have over 1,000 photos on the phone, and it takes several minutes for them to be all listed in the DCIM/Camera folder. And even longer for thumbnails to appear. Nothing appears to be cached for quick access.

Considering that MSD is no longer available, and MTP is excruciatingly slow, is there a better way to handle accessing photos on the phone and transferring them to a PC? I would prefer to avoid cloud services/features.

Comment: I have updated the answer to suit your needs, you might want to take a look at it and either accept the answer as valid or let me know why it won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's been a while since I asked this, but I think I finally came up with a decent solution that doens't involve the cloud, doesn't involve waiting eons for images to load via USB, and doesn't involve taking the phone apart to get at the SD card.

I created a file share on a computer, and installed ES File Explorer app on the phone. Using ES File Explorer, I access the file share, then go back to the home screen.

Then, in the android gallery, I select the photos I want to move to the computer, tap the "share" icon, and select the "ES save to" option. Then, go to the root direction, select the computer's name/IP, log in, select the appropriate folder on the computer, then tap "select" to upload the photos.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use [Air Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) Copy to comp, copy to phone [too long]

2) Switch on dropbox lan sync and transfer the photos by installing dropbox on your new phone too.

Both the methods will be a bit slow, but at least you can start the process and let things be taken care of.

[EDIT]
OP did not want cloud solutions, you can try out [Dukto](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.msec.dukto)
No intermediate required :) There you go

Comment: Both appear to be cloud-based solutions, which I would prefer to avoid. I don't want to upload my photos anywhere but my PC because of bandwidth limitations and privacy concerns.

Comment: Edited my answer to include Dukto, non cloud solution :)

Comment: I must say, Dukto looks promising

Answer (score 0):

I  have the same problems and many more with 4.4.4.

I found the fastest way to transfer pics and files is with a free app from Google Play that is called  SEND ANYWHERE. It works a whole lot better than anything else I've tried.

I sure do miss being able to just plug in the OTG to my Moto G XT1034 2298 and a flash drive to dump most any file I wanted into the flash drive. It was so very quick and easy. One of my biggest regrets was the moment I "upgraded" to the Android 4.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

As my own solution does not work for you on Windows (my windows are just for light and fresh air), I can only give you a pointer to some apps I didn't try myself.

On my server, you will find a list of apps to [Remotely manage media and files](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_remotemanagement#group_808). I'm no big cloud fan either, so in most of my lists I explicitely marked "cloud stuff" as such (so you can avoid it). None of the apps listed behind the link should use the cloud; they rather use your local WiFi network.

Scrolling to the end of that page, you will also find some "cable based" solutions, utilizing ADB – just in case you have no WiFi available.

As we always say to provide more than a link only (in case the page behind it dies – which I hope will not happen that soon to mine), let me name two of the solutions explicitly: [WebSharing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.websharing) is pretty popular, and [DavDrive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.fun2code.android.lite.webdrive) should be a decent solution as well.

Feel free to follow up the other links there for more information – it might well be you find something you'd like more, as it provides additional features (e.g. full remote device management ;)

Answer (score 0):

Total Commander for android with LAN (Windows shares) works the best for me..
You can access the whole disk structure of your pc from the phone, copy move delete, if you just login via the phone.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! You might want to include a link to the Application and how to set it up to make your answer even better :)

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. Android 4.4.4 on kid's older phone, needed the videos for his school project. Finally got the files over by sending as attachments via gmail.